# UEFI only recognizes /dev/sda, but not /dev/sda2, as bootable

Tags: boot, partition, uefi, manjaro, gparted

I have two bootable partitions, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda2`. However, when I restart my PC the UEFI bootsystem only recognizes the `/dev/sda` partition.

How do I fix this? I set the boot and esp flags to `/dev/sda2`, which contains a Manjaro ISO. `/dev/sda` contains a Solus ISO. I'm using the UEFI bootsystem, NOT Legacy boot. How can I set it to recognize `/dev/sda2` rather than `/dev/sda`?

Here is an image if it will better articulate what I'm trying to type.

[image: Partition layout]

Comment: UEFI only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in the ESP - efi system partition (the FAT32 one) for external devices. Only BIOS boot is thru MBR of a drive, which is not shown.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your trying to say, sorry. But I don't have any external devices and I was able to boot into /dev/sda (Solus OS) just fine.

Comment: It is extremely weird to have *multiple* iso9660 partitions on a hard drive; are you sure it's what you meant to do and could work?

Comment: Also: "boot to /dev/sda" and "boot to /dev/sda1" are quite different and it surprises me that sda boots at all when what you've displayed shows sda1 as the Solus partition. Are those labels accurate?

Answer (score 2):

The UEFI specification requires the firmware to support FAT32 for EFI System Partition, but it is allowed to support other filesystem types too. For example, Apple devices support HFS+ at the firmware level, and apparently at least some Asus motherboards support NTFS and ISO9660 in addition to FAT32.

It seems you've originally written the Solus ISO to `/dev/sda`, which is a whole-disk device, so the image must have included its own partition table, effectively creating `/dev/sda1` for you. That's what `isohybrid`-prepared ISO images do - and without such special preparation, an ISO will not be bootable at all when written onto a HDD-like storage device.

Technically, the `isohybrid` command uses the flexibility of the iso9660 format to prefix the image with a partition table (either MBR or GPT style) and then arrange things so that in addition to being a valid ISO image as a whole, it will also be possible to parse it as a raw disk image that includes a partition table and (usually) a single partition containing a ISO9660 filesystem.

If the Manjaro ISO also has been `isohybrid`-prepared, it also includes a partition table of its own. If you created `/dev/sda2` and wrote the ISO into it, there is now a partition table within a partition - and that is definitely not normal. Linux could sort of deal with it (with the help of `losetup` and/or `kpartx` commands, at least), but I would not be at all surprised if the system firmware cannot make sense of it.

(As far as I know, there is no official name for the arrangement that allows an ISO image to be also treated as a functional HDD image - but the `isohybrid` seems to have been the first tool to implement it.)

Your current partitioning scheme on `sda` can be interpreted in a total of three ways:

1. A "superfloppy" configuration: a valid ISO9660 filesystem (Solus) written into the whole-disk device `sda`, with some undefined garbage after the end of the filesystem (which would actually be the Manjaro ISO)
2. An apparently valid GPT partition table indicating the presence of two partitions: an ISO9660 filesystem (Solus) and a second ISO9660 filesystem (Manjaro).
3. The super-weird option: a GPT partition table indicating the presence of two partitions: an ISO9660 filesystem (Solus), and a second partition containing *another* partition table, which defines one partition with an ISO9660 filesystem in it (Manjaro)

It seems that your system firmware will test for case #1 before #2, and therefore prefers interpretation #1. Unfortunately, there may be nothing you can do to override that. If your firmware allows you to access an UEFI shell, you could use its `map` command to see how the firmware sees your disk... but not necessarily allow you to modify that.

As far as I know, no firmware nor OS will automatically accept interpretation #3, but with Linux you could pretty easily use `kpartx -a /dev/sda2` to parse that second partition table and generate a `/dev/mapper/sda2p1` device to access it, if you ever had need to do such a thing.

(You might find such a nested partition structure when dealing with Xen VMs set up with a VM system image on a partition device: although the image of the VM's system disk is on a partition, the VM sees it as a whole disk and so the OS installer will partition it. Now, if you have to modify some files within a VM that hangs at early boot to make it boot successfully again, you'll need to be able to deal with second-order partitions like this. I had to do something very much like this just last week!)